# File object reference parameter?

Tags: c++

How do I pass in a file object as a reference, for the sake of file reading?

Right now I have the following:

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, File &file)
{

}
```

but this gives me an error that 'File is not declared'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `File`? Is it your own class? Where is it declared?

Comment: 'File is not declared'

Comment: @interjay File is a text file that I need to read input from.

Comment: show the declaration of `File` - if it's a class written by you, that needs to be included / written above that operator (or forward-declared, like `class File;`)

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of overloading `operator>>`. You do that when you create a custom class. But it seems like you don't actually have a class named `File`.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look right at all. When reading from a file using C++ streams the file is the first parameter (the `istream& in`) and the second parameter is the object which you intend to populate using data from the file.

The `File is not declared` error indicates that the 'File' datatype you've specified for the second parameter doesn't exist.